# Terraform flatten tuple to set of string

Tags: string, azure, tuples, terraform, azure-rm

I have the following terraform allowed_ips tuple which contains a json of ip address and metadata about each ip. I am trying to flatten the tuple, to get a list of ip addresses in the format ["2.2.2.2", "3.3.3.3"] will then be passed to ip_rules variable

**Variable**

```
allowed_ips = [
    {
      name       = "ip1"
      ip_address = "3.3.3.3"
    },
    {

      name       = "ip2"
      ip_address = "127.0.0.1"
    }
  ]
```

**Resource**

```
variable "allowed_ips" {
  type = list(object({
    name       = string,
    priority   = string,
    ip_address = string
  }))
}

network_acls {
    default_action = "Deny"
    bypass         = "AzureServices"

    ip_rules =  jsonencode(var.allowed_ips.*.ip_address)
  }
```

When I set `ip_rules = ["2.2.2.2", "3.3.3.3"]` rules are created without issue but I would like somehow parse the variable from the allowed_ips above.

I have tried various ways including

- `jsonencode(var.allowed_ips.*.ip_address)`
- `"${join("\\,", local.subnets.*.id)}"`
- iterating via a foreach,

Unfortunately most of the solutions throw an error `Inappropriate value for attribute "ip_rules": set of string required.`

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a simple for loop to create a set:

```
ip_rules = [for i in var.allowed_ips : i.ip_address]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the `ip_rules` argument is expecting a value of type `set(string)`. If you wish to use the `allowed_ips` variable, you should be able to do something like the following:

```
ip_rules = toset(var.allowed_ips[*].ip_address)
```

The `jsonencode` function will encode the given value to a string, which is not the type that the `ip_rules` argument expects. The same can be said for the `join` function since its return value is of type string.